# How to use Application.InputBox to select a column?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I use the InputBox to select a cell and have the values of that column to be used? I trimmed most of the code out to make it fit so some of the variables will be undeclared.

Sub MacroForTransfers()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Declare variables for sheet names and adding new sheet
SheetName1 = "Original"
SheetName2 = "New"
ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName1
Sheets.Add.Name = SheetName2
Sheets(SheetName2).Select
' End of declare variables for sheet names

Dim shipDate, truckRoute, ware, custPurchaseOrder, jobName, shipVia As String
Dim unitSelect As Range

shipVia = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the ship via: ", Title:="Enter Ship Via", Default:="Enter two digit ship via here")
If shipVia = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If

shipDate = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the date order needs to ship (e.g. 040113): ", Title:="Enter Ship Date", Default:="Enter six digit ship date here")
If shipDate = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If

custPurchaseOrder = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter customer PO#: ", Title:="Enter Customer PO#", Default:="Enter customer PO# here")
If custPurchaseOrder = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If

ware = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter warehouse to receive transfer: ", Title:="Enter Warehouse to Receive Transfer", Default:="Enter three digit warehouse code here")
If ware = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If

jobName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter job name: ", Title:="Enter Job Name", Default:="Enter job name here")
If jobName = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If

truckRoute = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the truck route: ", Title:="Enter Truck Route", Default:="Enter two digit truck route here")
If truckRoute = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set unitSelect = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the unit column: ", Type:=8)


Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""a300002"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & shipVia & Chr(34)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & shipDate & Chr(34)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & custPurchaseOrder & Chr(34)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""man"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & ware & Chr(34)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & jobName & Chr(34)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & truckRoute & Chr(34)
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]"""

Sheets(SheetName1).Select ' Select the Original Sheet
lastRow = 65536
For row = 3 To lastRow
    item = Range("A" & row).Value
    If item <> "" Then
        Transfer = Range("U" & row).Value
        unit = unitSelect.Parent.Cells(row, unitSelect.Column).Value
            If Transfer > 0 Then
            Sheets(SheetName2).Select ' Select the New Sheet
            lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row ' Find the last cell that has data in Column A
            Range("A" & lastRow).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[backtab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""man"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & item & Chr(34)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[up]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & Transfer & Chr(34)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[field+]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & unit & Chr(34)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""b"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]"""
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]"""
            Sheets(SheetName1).Select ' Select the Original Sheet
        End If
    End If
Next row
Sheets(SheetName2).Select ' Select the New Sheet
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row ' Find the last cell that has data in Column A
Range("A" & lastRow).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[pf7]"""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[pf7]"""
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT]: I have revamped the code and tested it and it seems to be pulling from the selected column successfully:

```
Sub MacroForTransfers()

    Dim wsOld As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rngUnitSelect As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim arrOutput() As String
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strShipVia As String
    Dim strCustPurchaseOrder As String
    Dim strJobName As String
    Dim strWare As String
    Dim strTruckRoute As String
    Dim lShipDate As Long
    Dim OutputIndex As Long

    strShipVia = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the ship via: ", Title:="Enter Ship Via", Default:="Enter two digit ship via here", Type:=1)
    If Len(strShipVia) = 0 Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel

    lShipDate = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the date order needs to ship (e.g. 040113): ", Title:="Enter Ship Date", Default:="Enter six digit ship date here", Type:=1)
    If lShipDate = 0 Then Exit Sub  'Pressed cancel

    strCustPurchaseOrder = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter customer PO#: ", Title:="Enter Customer PO#", Default:="Enter customer PO# here")
    If Len(strCustPurchaseOrder) = 0 Then Exit Sub  'Pressed cancel

    strWare = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter warehouse to receive transfer: ", Title:="Enter Warehouse to Receive Transfer", Default:="Enter three digit warehouse code here")
    If Len(strWare) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

    strJobName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter job name: ", Title:="Enter Job Name", Default:="Enter job name here")
    If Len(strJobName) = 0 Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel

    strTruckRoute = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the truck route: ", Title:="Enter Truck Route", Default:="Enter two digit truck route here")
    If Len(strTruckRoute) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    On Error Resume Next    'Suppress error if user presses cancel
    Set rngUnitSelect = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the unit column: ", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0         'Remove the On Error Resume Next condition
    If rngUnitSelect Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

    If Not Evaluate("IsRef(Original!A1)") Then ActiveSheet.Name = "Original"
    If Not Evaluate("IsRef(New!A1)") Then Sheets.Add.Name = "New"
    Set wsOld = Sheets("Original")
    Set wsNew = Sheets("New")
    wsNew.UsedRange.Clear

    wsNew.Range("A1:A24").Value = Application.Transpose(Array("autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""a300002""", "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]""", _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & strShipVia & Chr(34), "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & lShipDate & Chr(34), _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]""", "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & strCustPurchaseOrder & Chr(34), _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]""", "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]""", _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""man""", "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]""", _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & strWare & Chr(34), "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]""", _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]""", "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]""", _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]""", "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]""", _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]""", "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[down]""", _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]""", "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]""", _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & strJobName & Chr(34), "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]""", _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & strTruckRoute & Chr(34), "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]""", _
                                                              "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[pf7]""", "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[pf7]"""))


    With wsOld.Range("A3:A" & Rows.Count)
        Set rngFound = .Find("*", wsOld.Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            ReDim arrOutput(1 To 21 * (.Rows.Count - WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells)))
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            Do
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 1) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[backtab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 2) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""man"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 3) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & rngFound.Value & Chr(34)
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 4) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[up]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 5) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 6) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 7) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 8) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 9) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 10) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 11) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & .Parent.Cells(rngFound.Row, "U").Value & Chr(34)
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 12) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[field+]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 13) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys " & Chr(34) & rngUnitSelect.Parent.Cells(rngFound.Row, rngUnitSelect.Column).Value & Chr(34)
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 14) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 15) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 16) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 17) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 18) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[tab]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 19) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""b"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 20) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]"""
                arrOutput(OutputIndex + 21) = "autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys ""[enter]"""
                OutputIndex = OutputIndex + 21
                Set rngFound = .Find("*", rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
            .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arrOutput)).Value = Application.Transpose(arrOutput)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error. It's not pulling the values out of the selected column though.

Comment: Did you set unit = to that value? like: `unit = unitSelect.Parent.Cells(row, unitSelect.Column).Value`

Comment: hmm? The question was "How do I use the InputBox to select a cell and have the values of that column to be used?"  In the code, there is already an Application.InputBox with Type:=8, so they have that much down.  It's just that when trying to use that selection, the original code was `unit = Range(unitSelect & row).Value` which is not a valid way of getting the data from the selected column, so I provided the valid way of doing so in my answer.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code I can't really give a more accurate answer.  The code I provided will pull the value of the selected column at the current row # (current row # is determined by your loop).  If that isn't working, then you have a different/additional problem that I can't really see due to lack of provided code and lack of context/sample data/expected results.

Comment: My objective for this macro is to create another macro for a different application.

Comment: @John Domingo, I have edited the answer, see if that works for you.  It tested successfully for me.